# If-else chain not returning correct results in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, predict

So I've recently started to really dig into different function types recently and am currently working on a function that takes in pregame info e.g(game time, home, away, betting odds) inserts that information into a predictive model and then outputs the predictions at the end. But I can't get the chain of if-else statements inside the original for loop to output the correct sentence I want.

Here is the structure of the function. I took out the actual model and manufactured the results for this question. The model is created outside of the function and uses the car::predict function

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)
#Here is an example of a data set that would be input into the function
x <- data.frame(home= c("CLE","MIL","DET"),away= c("BOS","IND","OKC"),O_U= c(215.5, 220.5, 209.5),linea= c("+","-","+"),lineb= c(4.0,11.0,8.5),gt= c("2020-02-20 19:00:00","2020-02-20 19:00:00","2020-02-20 19:00:00"))


predictor <- function(x){


gametime <- x[,6]
q <- x[,1] 
w <- x[,2]
OvUn <- x[,3]
linefavor <- x[,4]
spreadtot <- x[,5]


#I took the model out from here and just appended the results onto the end of the x dataframe. The model reproduced this exact table
y <- data.frame(HScore=c(105,114,105),AScore=c(117,106,110))
x <- cbind.data.frame(x,y)

# Here I put them in categories based off of the predictions(1 is true,0 is false,3 is Push)
x <- mutate(x, homewin = ifelse(HScore>AScore,1,0)) 
x <- mutate(x, underdog = ifelse(linefavor == "+",1, ifelse(linefavor == "-",0,"NA")))
x <- mutate(x, Over = ifelse(round(HScore)+round(AScore) > OvUn,1, ifelse(round(HScore)+round(AScore) < OvUn,0,3)))

x <- mutate(x,homecover = ifelse((underdog==1 & (round(HScore)+spreadtot)-round(AScore)>0) | (underdog==0 & (round(HScore)-spreadtot)-round(AScore)>0),1,
                                 ifelse((underdog==1 & (round(HScore)+spreadtot)-round(AScore)==0 | (underdog==0 & (round(HScore)-spreadtot)-round(AScore)==0)),3,0)))

print(x)

#Here is where my results become inaccurate. 
if(homewin ==1 & Over ==1 & homecover ==1){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",q," win ", round(x$HScore),"-",round(x$AScore),", ",q," cover ",linefavor,spreadtot," spread", " Over ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==1 & Over ==1 & homecover ==0){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",q," win ", round(x$HScore),"-",round(x$AScore),", ",w," cover ",linefavor2,spreadtot," spread", " Over ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==1 & Over ==0 & homecover ==0){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",q," win ", round(x$HScore),"-",round(x$AScore),", ",w," cover ",linefavor2,spreadtot," spread", " Under ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==1 & Over ==0 & homecover ==1){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",q," win ", round(x$HScore),"-",round(x$AScore),", ",q," cover ",linefavor,spreadtot," spread", " Under ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==0 & Over ==1 & homecover ==1){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",w," win ", round(x$AScore),"-",round(x$HScore),", ",q," cover ",linefavor,spreadtot," spread", " Over ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==0 & Over ==1 & homecover ==0){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",w," win ", round(x$AScore),"-",round(x$HScore),", ",w," cover ",linefavor2,spreadtot," spread", " Over ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==0 & Over ==0 & homecover ==0){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",w," win ", round(x$AScore),"-",round(x$HScore),", ",w," cover ",linefavor2,spreadtot," spread", " Under ",OvUn))
} else if(homewin ==0 & Over ==0 & homecover ==1){
  return(paste0(w," v ",q,": ",w," win ", round(x$AScore),"-",round(x$HScore),", ",q," cover ",linefavor,spreadtot," spread", " Under ",OvUn))


} else{
  return("ERROR")
}

  }

#Here is what my result looks like
predictor(x)
```

```
#Here is what it should look like
accurate <- c("BOS v CLE: BOS win 117-105, BOS cover -4 spread, Over 215.5","IND v MIL: MIL win 114-106, MIL cover -11 spread, Under 220.5","OKC v DET: OKC win 110-105, DET cover +8.5 spread, Over 209.5")
accurate
```

I have been stumped the last few days trying to figure out where is the origin of the problem.

Comment: One of the problems, if I can say this gently, is that your code is poorly formed.  I think you are trying to force R do things manually (e.g., with `if` `else` logic) that it might do rather simply.  Consider, e.g., using the the `data.frame` function at the beginning of your code (e.g., notice what happens with when you run `data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y = c("a", "b", "c"))`.)  Also, your `for` loop is not doing anything; you can remove the `for (i in example_x)` and you get the same result in `example_x`.  Post an example of the starting data and desired result and we might be able to help.

Comment: @GeoffreyPoole No offense taken. The criticism is helpful. I reformatted the question so its all reproducible and easier to look through. Hopefully this clears up what my problem looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do a Google search for "vector operations" in R.  It's a different way of thinking, and the default way of thinking in R.  You can't solve every problem with it, so R still has `for` loops, but you want to try to avoid them.

I don't understand sports betting enough to figure out who covers or doesn't cover what spread and the over/under stuff, but I can get you started on a simpler approach.

First, use the `$` operator to refer to a column in a data.frame as a vector.  That way, you don't have to assign the column to a different variable and your code is more readable.  As alternatives to `x$home`, you can also use `x[[1]]` or `x[["home"]]`.  (Note that `x["home"]` -- single brackets -- returns a one-column data.frame rather than a vector.)  I like using the column names rather than column numbers so that my code still works if the order of the columns gets changed around in the future.

Using the `x` data.frame from your example, I'd solve this problem by building character vectors that should be in each location of your desired output.  For instance.

```
winningTeam = ifelse(df$HScore > df$AScore, as.character(df$home), as.character(df$away))
winScore = pmax(x$HScore, x$AScore)
loseScore = pmin(x$HScore, x$AScore)
```

yields:

```
> winningTeam
[1] "BOS" "MIL" "OKC"
> winScore
[1] 117 114 110
> loseScore
[1] 105 106 105
```

You can use the same general approach to create vectors of who covered the spread, by how much, underdogs, etc.

Then, because the `paste` function deals with vectors, just `paste` together the vectors:

```
result = paste0(x$home, " v ", x$away, ": ", winningTeam, " win ", winScore, "-", loseScore)
```

The result is:

```
> result
[1] "CLE v BOS: BOS win 117-105" "MIL v IND: MIL win 114-106" "DET v OKC: OKC win 110-105"
```

Comment: Nice answer and explanation. I'd add that, for "fill-in-the-blank" string construction, I find that `sprintf` or `glue::glue` is often much more readable than `paste`. That would be something like `glue::glue_data(x, '{home} v {away}: {winningTeam} win {winScore}-{loseScore}')`, which reads very nicely. (`paste` is great for 2 or 3 strings, or for it's `collapse` argument.)

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful